# regex for obtaining entire text (anything) within [[ ]]

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have a text:

```
[[Hindi]]
[[Madras Talkies]]
[[Eros International]] [[A. R. *Rehman]]
```

I want to obtain everything within [[]] like

```
Hindi
Madras Talkies
Eros International
A. R. *Rehman
```

I tried couple of regex like:

```
        re.search('\[\[.*\]\]$',values)
    \[\[(\w+\s\w+)\]\](.*)$'
    \[\[(\w+)\]\]
```

Nothing is working for any of them. Can anyone suggest what's going wrong?

Comment: re.search is not going to work, it returns after finding the first match. Also note that * is greedy, which means that it will eat as much input as possible ([[a]][[b]] is eaten by one [[.*]]). For non-greedy one check *? .

Answer (score 2):

The following regex should do the trick:

```
\[\[(.*?)\]\]
```

What you need to do is make the wildcard `*` become lazy so it will only match w/e chars `.` matches until we can make a match with the last two brackets (thats not how it really works but it is the result).

This particular website may clear lazy/greedy up for you

http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#greedy

Answer (score 0):

You need a non-greedy search, so the regex should probably be:

```
\[\[(.*?)\]\]
```

If Python 2.7 doesn't support the non-greedy pattern (that's the `?` after `.*`), then you could use just `.*` but the third sample line with two sets of doubled square brackets will match just once, and the captured text will be:

```
Eros International]] [[A. R. *Rehman
```

With non-greedy matching, you'd get two separate matches on that line.

Comment: Can you imagine a regular expression engine *without* greedy/non-greedy support? Vim is the closest to such a thing that I'm aware of, where you would need to do `.*\{-}` instead of `.*?` (yet another of the sad deviations of Vim from what are now the established standards). Python certainly does support `.*?`.

Comment: Yes - lots of regular expression engines don't support non-greedy regexes; indeed, none of the classic Unix regex engines support them.  I am barely Python literate, but non-greedy regexes are a relatively new invention, and I've not investigated, much less internalized, when they were added to Python.

Comment: Hmm, so I see now. Didn't realise POSIX didn't support it. I guess I'm too young. Anyway, Python's `re` module is based on Perl regular expressions, not POSIX ones.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of matching a character if it exists + any extra characters like all of you guys here, I match what's not a **[** or **]** (minimum 1) inside **[[ ]]**

```
$ python2
>>> import re
>>> text = '[[Eros International]] [[A. R. *Rehman]]'
>>> re.findall('\[\[([^\[\]]+)\]\]', text)
['Eros International', 'A. R. *Rehman']
>>> re.findall('\[\[([^\[\]]+)\]\]', text)[0]
'Eros International'
>>> re.findall('\[\[([^\[\]]+)\]\]', text)[1]
'A. R. *Rehman'
```

Comment: This will not work if there are single `]` (non closing) brackest, like in `'[[A. R. [*]Reham]]'`

Comment: This is not in the user1036348 spec. Up to him to takes what's fits his needs.

Comment: *"I want to obtain everything within `[[` `]]`"*, it means that he want to handle that case too.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why you aren't just skiping the first two and the last two characters in the string?

```
s = ['[[Hindi]]',
     '[[Madras Talkies]]',
     '[[Eros International]]',
     '[[A. R. *Rehman]]']
names = [x[2:-2] for x in s]
```

Comment: String consists of of many brackets like this  [[]]<br>[[]] or [[]]<br/>[[]]